# Database Index Not working for column have value with colon (":")

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, oracle11g

Executing the Query Below, shows full scan in the explain plan of Query

```
SELECT A.TASK_ID 
FROM LOAN_TASK_MAPPING_MODEL A 
WHERE A.ASSIGNEE = 'com.nucleus.user.User:9032';
```

But if we remove ":" from 'com.nucleus.user.User:9032', it will start using the index created on ASSIGNEE column.

Please correct me what am i doing wrong? My database is oracle.

Comment: Show us both execution plans (**edit** your question, add them as *formatted* text). My guess is that with the colon Oracle expects much more rows to be returned than without.

Comment: Just a hint: the colon itself is not special and you're not doing anything "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to force to use the index with hint ?

I know its not a optimal answer but sometimes it helps.